# Speedbump for external links to support mailto links as well

Tags: javascript, regex

We have this speedbump code that presents the user with a notice they're about to leave the site (it's an ADA thing). It looks like it's done in regex, and I'm being asked to now support `mailto:` links as well. I'm the worst at regex and this is boggling my mind already. Does anyone have any pointers?

Here's the snippet that handles the evaluation of the hostname currently:

```
var re = new RegExp("^(http(s)?:)?\\/\\/([a-z0-9-_\\.]*\\.)?(" + whitelist.join("|").replace(/\./g, "\\.") + ")(\\/.*)?$", "i");

$('a').each(function() {
    var hrefTest = $(this).attr('href');

    if (hrefTest) {
        if (!re.test(hrefTest) && (hrefTest.substring(0,4) == 'http')) {
            $(this).addClass('speedbump-enabled');
        }
    }
});
```

Essentially, if the link the user is clicking doesn't match the current hostname, we present them with a popup, alerting them that they're about to leave the site.

The whitelist portion is a separate logic that allows for a whitelist of hostnames to ignore for the speedbump popup (ie., which hostnames to not show it for).

**Update & Possible Solution**

I ended up changing:

```
if ( !re.test(hrefTest) && (hrefTest.substring(0,4) == 'http') ) {
```

...to...

```
if ( !re.test(hrefTest) && ( (hrefTest.substring(0,4) == 'http') || (hrefTest.substring(0,6) == 'mailto') ) ) {
```

This seems to have done the trick for `mailto` links, but not 100% sure yet. Still testing to confirm it's a viable solution.

Comment: Perhaps change `http(s)?:` to `((http(s)?|mailto):)`, which extends support for `http` and `https` to include `mailto` through the regex group operator.

Comment: Why would you need this feature for mailto links? Clicking on them doesn't cause a user's browser to leave the site.

Comment: I know, and I agree @CAustin, but I've already made this case to the client and they've stubbornly requested it anyways. Unfortunately this change it going to happen.

Comment: In that case, I'm still a bit confused. Does the speedbump need to happen when the email address's domain isn't on the whitelist?

Comment: The client's 3rd party vendor for accessibility claimed that since the mailto links took you to a place different than the current website (in this case, to an email application) that the speedbump should apply there as well. I realize this isn't the norm, and thank you for your questions!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the official Definition of mailto: Links, but following regex match all examples mentioned on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto)

```
mailto:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)?(?:,[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)*(?:[\?\&](?:(?:subject)|(?:body)|(?:b?cc)|(?:to))=[^\&\?\n]*)*
```

For the testcases see [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MHmmQH/1)